# Where do I install a New Relic plugin in a Rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, newrelic-platform

I want to install a [Redis plugin](http://newrelic.com/plugins/pivotal/124) for New Relic. I have looked at the instructions for those plugins, and gone over the general [Ruby plugin instructions](https://newrelic.com/docs/plugins/ruby-plugin-installation-example). I understand how to change the config file, but for the life of me I can't figure out where in my rails app to actually put the plugin.

Where should it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The New Relic plugins are actually stand-alone processes that do not integrate directly with Rails or any other process. You can run the plugin on any server you want. Maybe the server running Redis would be a good choice since the plugin will be connecting to Redis regularly to collect the metrics that it sends to New Relic.